# Jquery events Draggable,Resizeable do not work with html '<object>' Tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using Jquery Ui in a project where html objects like `<img>` and `<div>` are dragged and resized but for interactive SVG I had to go for `<object>` to draw and change svg element. But at this stage I am not able to drag and resize the element.

I have tried this to make it draggable and resizeable

```
var newcanvas = $(`<object>`).attr("data","http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/80/Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg").css("width","100%");

newcanvas.resizable();
newcanvas.draggable();
```

**Note**: newcanvas is a dynamic added object to some div but the same case is working correct with `<img>` tag and other but not with object tag

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It may be best to include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Based on your description, as long as `<object>` is part of the DOM and has a Box model, these should work. Do you see any errors in console?

Answer (score 1):

Did a little bit of research and `<object>` is an element yet it doesn't seem to be rendered. Consider the following tests:

```js
$(function() {
  function makeObject(d, t) {
    if (t == undefined) {
      t = $(".page");
    }
    var newcanvas = $(`<object>`).attr("data", d).css("width", "50%");
    newcanvas.appendTo(t);
    return newcanvas;
  }

  $("#makeObject").click(function() {
    var c = makeObject("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/80/Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg");
    c.draggable().resizable();
  });
  $("#clearObject").click(function() {
    $("object, .objectWrap").remove();
  });
  $("#wrapObject").click(function() {
    var w = $("<div>", {
      class: "objectWrap"
    }).css({
      width: "200px",
      height: "200px"
    }).appendTo(".page");
    var c = makeObject("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/80/Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg", w);
    c.css("width", "100%");
    w.draggable().resizable();
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="page">
  <div class="tools">
    <button id="makeObject">Make Object</button>
    <button id="clearObject">Clear Object</button>
    <button id="wrapObject">Make Object w/Wrap</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would advise wrapping the `<object>` with a `<div>` and then applying draggable and resizable to this. This is discussed in a few other scenarios in Stack Overflow. In the future, make sure to search thoroughly.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I have definitely applied this solution to pack this `<object>` tag into a div and then applied the draggable and resizeable event on div.But it doesn't seem to work. You can test your own snippet in which draggable is not working even after wrapping up the div. Resizable works but it also stucks and doesn't work efficiently..